# Unzip list of files from bash associative array keys

Tags: bash, associative-array, unzip

My bash script create an associative array with files as keys.

```
declare -A fileInFolder
for f in "${zipFolder}/"*".zip"; do
    read -r fileInFolder[$f] _ < <(md5sum "$f")
done

... code for removing some entry in fileInFolder ...

unzip -qqc "${!fileInFolder[@]}"
```

And `unzip` prevent me `caution: filename not matched:` for everyone except first file.

The following command work without any problem:

```
unzip -qqc "${zipFolder}/"\*".zip"
```

I try using `7z` but I did't find the way to give more than one zip file as input (using `-ai` option [this need a list of file separated by new line](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/ar_include.htm) if my understanding is correct...)

Comment: From your description (_`unzip` give me_) it looks like the use of `awk` is not relevant at all, since the error occurs in `unzip`. Is this correct?

Comment: You can directly do `read -r fileInFolder[$f] _ < <(md5sum "$f")`

Comment: @LéaGris simplified code with your proposal

Comment: I added an alternate method to only call md5sum once for all zip files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ignoring the reason for the Associative array storing MD5 of zip files.
- As @Enrico Maria De Angelis pointed-out, `unzip` only accepts one zip file argument per invocation. So you can not expand the associative array file names indexes into arguments for a single call to `unzip`.

I propose this solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# You don't want to unzip the pattern name if none match
shopt -s nullglob

declare -A fileInFolder
for f in "${zipFolder}/"*".zip"; do
    # Store MD5 of zip file into assoc array fileInFolder
    # key: zip file name
    # value: md5sum of zip file
    read -r fileInFolder["$f"] < <(md5sum "$f")
    # Unzip file content to stdout
    unzip -qqc "$f"
done | {
 # Stream the for loop's stdout to the awk script
 awk -f script.awk
}
```

Alternative implementation calling md5sum only once for all zip files

```sh
shopt -s nullglob

# Iterate the null delimited entries output from md5sum
# Reading first IFS=' ' space delimited field as sum
# and remaining of entry until null as zipname
while IFS=' ' read -r -d '' sum zipname; do
  # In case md5sum file patterns has no match
  # It will return the md5sum of stdin with file name -
  # If so, break out of the while
  [ "$zipname" = '-' ] && break
  fileInFolder["$zipname"]="$sum"
  # Unzip file to stdout
  unzip -qqc -- "$zipname"
done < <(md5sum --zero -- "$zipFolder/"*'.zip' </dev/null) | awk -f script.awk
```

Answer (score 1):

### Foreword

This answer, which basically boils down to *you can't do this with one `unzip` command*, assumes you are aware you can put `unzip -qqc "$f"` in the `for` loop you wrote in your question, and that you don't want to do it for some reason.

### My answer

You are not getting an error for **all** files; rather, you are getting an error for all files **from the second one on**.

Simply try the following

```
unzip -qqc file1.zip file2.zip
```

and you will get the error

```
caution: filename not matched:  file2.zip
```

which is just the one you are getting.

From the `unzip`'s `man` page

> ````
> SYNOPSIS
>        unzip [-Z] [-cflptTuvz[abjnoqsCDKLMUVWX$/:^]] file[.zip] [file(s) ...]  [-x xfile(s) ...] [-d exdir]```
> ````

it looks like you are only allowed to provide **one** `zip` file on the command line.

Well, actually not quite, in that you can specify more `zip` files on the command line, but to do so, you have to rely on `unzip`'s own way of interpreting its own command line; this partly mimics the shell, but all it can do is listed in the `man` page:

> ````
> ARGUMENTS
>        file[.zip]
>               Path of the ZIP archive(s).  If the file specification is a wildcard, each matching file is processed in an order determined by  the
>               operating system (or file system).  Only the filename can be a wildcard; the path itself cannot.  Wildcard expressions are similar to
>               those supported in commonly used Unix shells (sh, ksh, csh) and may contain:
>
>               *      matches a sequence of 0 or more characters
>
>               ?      matches exactly 1 character
>
>               [...]  matches any single character found inside the brackets; ranges are specified by a beginning character, a hyphen, and an ending
>                      character.   If an exclamation point or a caret (`!' or `^') follows the left bracket, then the range of characters within the
>                      brackets is complemented (that is, anything except the characters inside the brackets is considered a match).   To specify  a
>                      verbatim left bracket, the three-character sequence ``[[]'' has to be used.
>
>               (Be  sure to quote any character that might otherwise be interpreted or modified by the operating system, particularly under Unix and
>               VMS.)  If no matches are found, the specification is assumed to be a literal filename; and if that also fails, the suffix .zip is ap‐
>               pended.   Note that self-extracting ZIP files are supported, as with any other ZIP archive; just specify the .exe suffix (if any) ex‐
>               plicitly. ```
> ````

So you are technically facing the same issue you've found with `7z`.

Comment: Just loop the array indexes and pipe the loop to awk script: `for f in "${!fileInFolder[@]}"; do unzip -qqc "$f"; done | awk -f script.awk`

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for this solution, otherwise why creating an associative array in the first place? He could just shove `unzip -qqc "$f"` in the `for` loop he's already written in the question.

Comment: I guessed @Nathanaël stored the MD5 of zip files in the assoc array for other not mentioned purpose. He indeed could directly do the unzip to stdout from the same loop to populate the assoc array and pipe the same loop to the awk script.

Comment: @LéaGris piping the loop to `awk` did the tricks! Can not up-vote comment but this is the solution for me.